# Flutter - Auto size AlertDialog to fit list content

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, size, android-alertdialog

I need to load list cities dynamically from rest webservice and let user choose a city from alert dialog.
My code:

```
createDialog() {

    fetchCities().then((response) {

      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Wybierz miasto'),
              content: Container(
                height: 200.0,
                width: 400.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: response.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(response[index].name),
                      onTap: () => citySelected(response[index].id),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      );
    });
  }
```

Result - dialog is always 200x400, even if only 2 cities are available, there is an unnecessary room left at the bottom:

[image]

How to make dialog width/height to fit actual items size? If I ommit `height` and `width` parameters, I'm getting exception and no dialog shown. In native Android Java I never need to specify any dimensions, because dialog sizes itself automatically to fit.

How to fix my code to get dialog sized correctly? Note: that I don't know item count, it's dynamic.

[edit]

As suggested, I wrapped content with column:

```
createDialog() {
    fetchCities().then((response) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Wybierz miasto'),
              content: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: response.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(response[index].name),
                            onTap: () => citySelected(response[index].id),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ]
              ),
            );
          }
      );
    });
  }
```

Result - exception:

> I/flutter ( 5917): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
> ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter (
> 5917): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> I/flutter ( 5917): RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic
> dimensions. I/flutter ( 5917): Calculating the intrinsic dimensions
> would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which
> I/flutter ( 5917): defeats the point of viewports being lazy.

More generic code to test:

```
showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (BuildContext context) {
         return AlertDialog(
           title: Text('Select city'),
           content: Column(
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
               children: <Widget>[
                 Container(
                   child: ListView.builder(
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     itemCount: 2,
                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                       return ListTile(
                         title: Text("City"),
                         onTap: () => {},
                       );
                     },
                   ),
                 )
               ]
           ),
         );
       }
   );
```

Comment: Try taking the width and height values off of your container?

Comment: What do you mean? If width, height are missing I am getting exception 'RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.'

Answer (score 248):

Wrap your `Container` inside a `Column`, in the content parameter, inside of it, set the `mainAxisSize.min`, in Column property

```dart
Container(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      ...
    ],
  )
)
```

Comment: Worked! 

`Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        //list
      ],
    );`

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm.
I had no clue that  it defaultes to `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`.. Makes sense.

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Comment: Container is not required. Just mainAxisSize is enough.

Answer (score 70):

I know it's quite late, but have you tried this?

```
Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
       Container(
         child: ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           ...
         ),
       )
    ],
);
```

Comment: This worked for me! It starts expanding unnecessarily everytime I use a Flexible widget. Widgets of fixed sizes seem to be using the space efficiently.

Comment: This for me is as good as calling ```wrap_content``` onto the widget :)

Comment: Wow! It was very simple solution, it was enough to add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

Comment: Thanks. >> mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

Answer (score 53):

**Don't set `mainAxisSize.min` in your `Column`** otherwise you might run into overflow error if the content is longer than the viewport. To solve this issue, use either of the approaches.

#### 1. Set `scrollable: true` in `AlertDialog`:

```dart
AlertDialog(
  scrollable: true, // <-- Set it to true
  content: Column(
    children: [...],
  ),
)
```

#### 2. Wrap `Column` in `SingleChildScrollView`:

```dart
AlertDialog(
  content: SingleChildScrollView( 
    child: Column(
      children: [...],
    ),
  ),
)
```

#### 3. Set `shrinkWrap: true` in `ListView`:

```dart
AlertDialog(
  content: SizedBox(
    width: double.maxFinite,
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, // <-- Set this to true
      children: [...],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 17):

I have a similar problem.
I fixed it by adding: `scrollable: true` in AlertDialog

Updated Code will be :

```
 createDialog() {
    fetchCities().then((response) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              scrollable: true,
              title: Text('Wybierz miasto'),
              content: Container(
                height: 200.0,
                width: 400.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: response.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(response[index].name),
                      onTap: () => citySelected(response[index].id),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Added it, but now I am getting  
Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.

Comment: adding `scrollable` ass here solved the issue for me, thanks

Comment: Adding only `scrollable` solved my issue

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a lazy viewport like listView and wrap the column with a SingleChildScrollView

> AlertDialog tries to size itself using the intrinsic dimensions of
> its children, widgets such as ListView, GridView, and
> CustomScrollView, which use lazy viewports, will not work. Consider
> using a scrolling widget for large content, such as
> SingleChildScrollView, to avoid overflow. Read more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)!

So you have something like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(          
   child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
           Container(
             child: ListView.builder(
               shrinkWrap: true,
           ...
         ),
       )
    ],
);
```

Comment: But using a `ListView` works as expected.

Comment: Only  listview? Can you share a code snippet.

Comment: `ListView`, `GridView`, ... it works in all cases. Here's the [sample code](https://gist.github.com/iLoveDocs/2216f6ce222d09d5985b346a4c081f77)

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at how SimpleDialog does it.

```
Widget dialogChild = IntrinsicWidth(
  stepWidth: 56.0,
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        if (title != null)
          Padding(
            padding: titlePadding,
            child: DefaultTextStyle(
              style: theme.textTheme.title,
              child: Semantics(namesRoute: true, child: title),
            ),
          ),
        if (children != null)
          Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: contentPadding,
              child: ListBody(children: children),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem and I came up with a solution that works for both Material and Cupertino.

The performance (especially if the list of elements gets long) as compared to what the alert dialogs with scrollable flag = true and a Column with mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min have to offer is way way better both loading and scrolling of the contents - just have a look at the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nKTGFZosr0

Also the title of the dialog does not get "scrolled up" with the rest of the elements (similar to your solution), so you can add say a filtering tool at the top and display only the elements that match a search phrase.

The source code is available here https://github.com/hicnar/fluttery_stuff Just checkout the whole thing and run the main() located in lib/dialogs/main.dart Obviously you can copy, paste, modify and use it in any way you like. No copyrights here.

Finally, in the example I have limited the height of the ListView based dialog content to max 45% height of the screen, you will find it with ease and if you change the factor to 1.0 you will get the same sizing behaviour as from the Column based approach (search for a field named screenHeightFactor)

Answer (score 1):

```
return AlertDialog(
  shape: ShapeConstant.shapeBorder(radius: 18, borderSide: false),
  actionsPadding: PaddingConstant.defaultPadding16,
  insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(64.0),
  contentPadding: PaddingConstant.defaultPadding,
  title: BaseDialogTopBar.baseDialogTopBar(
      isVisible: false,
      text: StringConst.settingText9,
      onSubmit: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }),
  actions: [
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Buttons.basePositiveBtn(
          width: 200,
          widgetKey: "widgetKey",
          text: "add",
          onSubmit: () {
            debugPrint("callClick");
          }),
    )
  ],
  content: SizedBox(
    width: 500,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: colorList.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(colorList[index]),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, colorList[index]);
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this out?
It worked at least for me.
If you need an example tell me.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SmartDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const SmartDialog({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.titlePadding,
    this.content,
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0),
    this.actions,
    this.semanticLabel,
  }) : assert(contentPadding != null),
       super(key: key);

  final Widget title;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;
  final Widget content;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding;
  final List<Widget> actions;
  final String semanticLabel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    String label = semanticLabel;

    if (title != null) {
      children.add(new Padding(
        padding: titlePadding ?? new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, content == null ? 20.0 : 0.0),
        child: new DefaultTextStyle(
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          child: new Semantics(child: title, namesRoute: true),
        ),
      ));
    } else {
      switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
        case TargetPlatform.iOS:
          label = semanticLabel;
          break;
        case TargetPlatform.android:
        case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
          label = semanticLabel ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context)?.alertDialogLabel;
      }
    }

    if (content != null) {
      children.add(new Flexible(
        child: new Padding(
          padding: contentPadding,
          child: new DefaultTextStyle(
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
            child: content,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    if (actions != null) {
      children.add(new ButtonTheme.bar(
        child: new ButtonBar(
          children: actions,
        ),
      ));
    }

    Widget dialogChild = new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: children,
    );

    if (label != null)
      dialogChild = new Semantics(
        namesRoute: true,
        label: label,
        child: dialogChild
      );

    return new Dialog(child: dialogChild);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You just need to show this AreaPicker after button or something pressed.

```
class AreaPicker extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Area> items;
  AreaPicker(this.items);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SmartDialog(
      title: Text('Select Area'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          textColor: Colors.black,
          child: Text('Rather not say'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
          },
        )
      ],
      content: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemExtent: 70.0,
          itemCount: areas.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final Area area = areas[index];
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(area.name),
              ),
              onTap: () { 
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                // some callback here.
              }
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How to use it in my example?

Comment: I added generic code not bound to my data source, for quick testing. It throws exception.

Comment: I want to show alertDialog, with list view inside. Look at picture I included in my question.

Comment: As I can see, you wrote custom dialog, but I'm not sure how to show it

Comment: My result: https://i.imgur.com/fCAJCJA.png text is centered and extra room is also there

Comment: I ended with this (poor solution): assume some height for single list item and calculate final dialog height as multiplication of items count

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So that's my final solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(T item);

class CityChoiceDialog<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T initialValue;
  final List<T> items;
  final ValueChanged<T> onSelected;
  final ValueChanged<T> onSubmitted;
  final ValueChanged<T> onCancelled;
  final Widget title;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding;
  final String semanticLabel;
  final ItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder;
  final List<Widget> actions;
  final Color activeColor;
  final String cancelActionButtonLabel;
  final String submitActionButtonLabel;
  final Color actionButtonLabelColor;

  final Widget divider;

  CityChoiceDialog({
    Key key,
    this.initialValue,
    @required this.items,
    this.onSelected,
    this.onSubmitted,
    this.onCancelled,
    this.title,
    this.titlePadding,
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    this.semanticLabel,
    this.actions,
    this.itemBuilder,
    this.activeColor,
    this.cancelActionButtonLabel,
    this.submitActionButtonLabel,
    this.actionButtonLabelColor,
    this.divider = const Divider(height: 0.0),
  })  : assert(items != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _CityChoiceDialogState<T> createState() =>
      _CityChoiceDialogState<T>();
}

class _CityChoiceDialogState<T>
    extends State<CityChoiceDialog<T>> {
  T _chosenItem;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _chosenItem = widget.initialValue;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyAlertDialog(
      title: widget.title,
      titlePadding: widget.titlePadding,
      contentPadding: widget.contentPadding,
      semanticLabel: widget.semanticLabel,
      content: _buildContent(),
      actions: _buildActions(),
      divider: widget.divider,
    );
  }

  _buildContent() {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: widget.items
          .map(
            (item) => RadioListTile(
          title: widget.itemBuilder != null
              ? widget.itemBuilder(item)
              : Text(item.toString()),
          activeColor:
          widget.activeColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          value: item,
          groupValue: _chosenItem,
          onChanged: (value) {
            if (widget.onSelected != null) widget.onSelected(value);
            setState(() {
              _chosenItem = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      )
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  _buildActions() {
    return widget.actions ??
        <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor:
            widget.actionButtonLabelColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            child: Text(widget.cancelActionButtonLabel ?? 'ANULUJ'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              if (widget.onCancelled!= null) widget.onCancelled(_chosenItem);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            textColor:
            widget.actionButtonLabelColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            child: Text(widget.submitActionButtonLabel ?? 'WYBIERZ'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              if (widget.onSubmitted != null) widget.onSubmitted(_chosenItem);
            },
          )
        ];
  }
}

class MyAlertDialog<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyAlertDialog({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.titlePadding,
    this.content,
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0),
    this.actions,
    this.semanticLabel,
    this.divider = const Divider(
      height: 0.0,
    ),
    this.isDividerEnabled = true,
  })  : assert(contentPadding != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Widget title;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;
  final Widget content;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding;
  final List<Widget> actions;
  final String semanticLabel;
  final Widget divider;

  final bool isDividerEnabled;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    String label = semanticLabel;

    if (title != null) {
      children.add(new Padding(
        padding: titlePadding ??
            new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                24.0, 24.0, 24.0, isDividerEnabled ? 20.0 : 0.0),
        child: new DefaultTextStyle(
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          child: new Semantics(child: title, namesRoute: true),
        ),
      ));
      if (isDividerEnabled) children.add(divider);
    } else {
      switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
        case TargetPlatform.iOS:
          label = semanticLabel;
          break;
        case TargetPlatform.android:
        case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
          label = semanticLabel ??
              MaterialLocalizations.of(context)?.alertDialogLabel;
      }
    }

    if (content != null) {
      children.add(new Flexible(
        child: new Padding(
          padding: contentPadding,
          child: new DefaultTextStyle(
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
            child: content,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    if (actions != null) {
      if (isDividerEnabled) children.add(divider);
      children.add(new ButtonTheme.bar(
        child: new ButtonBar(
          children: actions,
        ),
      ));
    }

    Widget dialogChild = new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: children,
    );

    if (label != null)
      dialogChild =
      new Semantics(namesRoute: true, label: label, child: dialogChild);

    return new Dialog(child: dialogChild);
  }
}
```

It's based on https://pub.dev/packages/easy_dialogs and so far it works fine. I'm sharing it, as it may be useful, problem is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said about content part, wrap AlertDialog with [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) to give a dynamic height and width to the art box.

Answer (score 0):

I try not to use shrinkWrap with long lists. I measure how many items are expected to fill the available space and add a few to make sure that there is no strange behavior.

```dart
// e.g. dialog should be no bigger than 70% of the screen
final maximumHeightOfDialog = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7;
Dialog(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: maximumHeightOfDialog,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              // probably title or sth
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              // better than Expanded as it does not force to fill the available space, 
              //but only takes as much as necessary
              Flexible(
                child: AnimatedSize( // animate changes in size, when the list 
                  //size is changing, e.g. search functionality
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: options.length,
                    // e.g. I expect only 10 items to fill my screen, 
                    //so I added 2 additional items. I get better 
                    //performance with shrinkWrap = false when there are lots of items
                    shrinkWrap: options.length < 12,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return SomeItem()
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 28,
              ),
              // action buttons
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```